# Prove that, If $p > 0$ and $\Bbb{E}(|X|^p )< \infty$, then $x^p \Bbb{P}(\{ |X|>x\}) \sim o(1)$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Prove that, If $p > 0$ and $\Bbb{E}(|X|^p )< \infty$, then $x^p \Bbb{P}(\{ |X|>x\}) \sim o(1)$ as $x \to \infty$

I tried to solve this question in class but I ended up with the difficult form of an equation that seems to be difficult to integrate.

Comment: Please use MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb{E}[|X|^p]<\infty$ then $|X|<\infty$ a.s., hence $x^p1_{|X|>x}\to 0$ pointwise a.s. as $x\to\infty$.

Moreover, $x^p1_{|X|>x}\leq |X|^p$ , so it follows from the dominated convergence theorem that
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}x^p\mathbb{P}(|X|>x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[x^p1_{|X|>x}]=0$$

Comment: well, I try to read on the dominated convergence theorem since I never studied it before but I didn't absorb much knowledge. How did you use that theorem to make it converge to zero? sorry, will you show how it converge?